# Give webservice access to windows service

Tags: security, command-line, windows-services, windows-server-2008

I am running a webservice on server 2008 that needs access to a windows service and I need to give access to [the user that the web service is running as] via the command line.

(sorry if my wording is terrible, hopefully the brackets helped?).

I know there is a utility available with the windows 2000 resource kit (SUBINACL.exe), but is there one available in server 08 that doesn't require downloading a resource kit?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you talking of a one-time change of the ACL/ACE, as so to provide access to the webservice account to whatever resources/access the Windows service requires,  or is there a need to mess with ACEs with each new request to the web service ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For everyone else wondering how to do this...

Microsoft offers a utility available for download called [Subinacl.exe](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=E8BA3E56-D8FE-4A91-93CF-ED6985E3927B&displaylang=en) that allows you to do just this.

```
subinacl.exe /service <serviceName> /grant=Domain\AccountName=<AccessType>
```

For info on the different access types and on the utility in general...

```
subinacl.exe /help /full
```